# Получение двумерного массива изображения Python

Tags: python, numpy, pil, bmp

Нужно загрузить порядка 100 изображений,черно-белые с оттенками серого(оттенки не особо важны), глубиной 24 бита, размером 24*24 в формате .bmp для дальнейшей обработки. Хранить нужно в np.array. Конечный массив должен представлять из себя <100,24,24>
Делаю следующее:

```
for filename in glob.glob('set_number/*.bmp'): #assuming bmp
    im=Image.open(filename)
    arr = np.asarray(im, dtype='float64')
    image.append(arr)

my_images=np.array(image, dtype='float64')
my_images=my_images/255.0

print(my_images.shape)
```

Следовательно массив получается <100,24,24,3>
Можно ли как то с помощью имеющиеся в numpy или PIL функций привести это к виду <100,24,24>? или если нельзя то как лучше это сделать?

Если это поможет то скажу что в дальнейшем этот масcив используется в TensorFlow (model.fit())

Comment: Там 3 байта - по байту на цвет. И что вы хотите - собрать их вместе?

Comment: Битмапы цветные, 24-битные? Что тогда должно лежать в каждом элементе массива?

Comment: @splash58 Да, просто записать среднее всех цветов

Comment: @MBo сами изображения черно белые, с оттенками серого, в каждом элементе может лежать среднее всех цветов, после деления на 255 это должно привести значения массива к диапазону от 0 до 1

Comment: Т.е. битмапы монохромные (8 бит на пиксел) ? (судя по "среднее всех цветов", это не так)

Comment: @MBo Нет, 24 бита, лично сохранял. Эти изображения используются еще  в одном проекте и там они нужны такие

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, вот такой у вас массив с изображением для 2х2

```
arr
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6]],  
       [[ 7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12]]])
```

И что-то такое вы хотите получить? Уменьшить размерность на 1, заменив на среднее

```
arr.mean(axis=2)
array([[  2.,   5.],
       [  8.,  11.]])
```

В принципе, чтоб  усреднить самый глубокий уровень, можно написать

```
ndArray.mean(axis=len(ndArray.shape)-1)
```

Comment: Да, так и есть, такой результат и нужен)

Comment: Спасибо, все отлично работает)

Answer (score 1):

В описанном случае функции загрузки не знают, что изображение серое, и сохраняют все каналы в rgb. В OpenCV для выделения отдельных каналов используется split, здесь numpy позволяет сделать (если каналы уже равны)

```
gray = my_images[:, :, :, 0]
```

Comment: После такого изменения массив стал <100,24,3> o_O

Comment: Я одно измерение потерял

Comment: Спасибо за решение, все работает :3 Жаль что отметить можно только один ответ :С